# transform array and object to customized object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, vue.js

I want to write a function that transfers this objects

```
const input1 = ["monkey","bananas"];

const input2 = {
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "monkey.play",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "monkey.run",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "bananas.eat",
  },
};
```

to be like a thing like that

```
const output = [
  {
    name: "monkey",
    actions: ["play","run"],
    
  },
{
    name: "bananas",
    actions: ["eat"],
    
  },
];
```

I tried with Array.reduce, but I don't know how to render this. If anyone has any hindsight on this I want to merge the two inputs using postid, so can i use map to loop or reduce,I will be very grateful if someone can help me to do that and also if you have any reduce/map tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is another approach by simply looping over your two inputs. Notice, that your second input needs to be an array, too.

By splitting the string you can check if the names match and pass the value to the actions.

```js
const input1 = ["monkey", "bananas"];

const input2 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "monkey.play",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "monkey.run",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "bananas.eat",
  },
];

const output = input1.map(inputName => {
    // create the new object structre
    const obj = {
        name: null,
        actions: []
    }
    // loop over the second input, split the strings
    input2.forEach(action => {
        const inputAction = action.name.split('.')
        // check if the first string matches your input1 and push the value via index into the actions array
        if (inputAction[0] === inputName) obj.actions.push(inputAction[1])
    })
    obj.name = inputName // assing the name to the object
    return obj
})
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your `input2` object is not a correct structure. You will need to use square brackets instead of curly braces.

Now, you can reduce each item by splitting the `name` field and using the first part as the local "name" and the second part as the "action". While reducing, you can build the action list by concatenating using the spread operator on the existing (or new) array. Lastly, take your new object you reduced and extract the values.

```js
const input = [
  { id: 1, name: "monkey.play" },
  { id: 2, name: "monkey.run"  },
  { id: 3, name: "bananas.eat" }
];

const ouptut = Object.values(input.reduce((acc, { id, name }) =>
  (([_name, _action]) =>
    ({
      ...acc,
      [_name]: {
        ...acc[_name],
        name: _name,
        actions: [...(acc[_name]?.actions || []), _action]
      }
    }))
  (name.split(/\./)), {}));
  
console.log(ouptut);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner alternative to the already supplied answers:

```
const output = input1.map(name => ({
  name,
  actions: input2.filter(obj => 
    obj.name.split('.')[0] === name)
    .map(obj => obj.name.split('.')[1])
}));
```

assuming input2 is also an array.